# Getting User Entered Form Data within a hook function

Tags: forms, commerce

**Problem**

I need to use the following **hook** function to edit a similarly-named function in a contributed module ([PayPal WPP](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_paypal)), but I don't understand how to use it.

```
hook_commerce_paypal_api_request_alter(&$nvp, $order, $payment_method) { }
```

When this function is called I need to pass some variables to **PayPal**, based off **user-supplied input in a form**. **By the time this function is called the user has already supplied their input in the form and clicked 'submit'**. The form is now ready to send it's data to PayPal and this hook alters what is being sent.

So I need to figure out how to add additional data. Specifically I want to alter a variable $nvp['custom']. **The main problem is I don't know how to get the values the user entered in the form into this function so I can pass them on.**

I'm told I need to get the user-supplied values using `$form_state['values']` but I have no idea how to get those inside this function, which isn't passed `$form_state` as a parameter. I was hoping to do something like this:

```
$name = $form_state['values']['field_name'];
$organization = $form_state['values']['field_organization'];
$arr = array($name, $organization);
$allthedata = implode('+', $arr);
$nvp['CUSTOM'] = $allthedata;
```

*As it may be obvious I don't even know how to refer correctly to the passed $form_state values, which is probably a large part of my problem.*

**Question**

How do i get my user-supplied form values into this function so I can use them (and then pass them on to PayPal as part of the $nvp['custom'] variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can user this code in which you can add your form data in array and pass it to the Paypal api.

```
function do_custom_commerce_paypal_api_request_alter(&$nvp, $order, $payment_method){
    if ($payment_method['base'] == 'commerce_paypal_wpp' ) { //check payment method

        //save form data
        $name = $form_state['values']['field_name'];
        $organization = $form_state['values']['field_organization'];

        $nvp += array(
        'name' => $name,
        'organization' => $organization,
    );
  }
}
```

Here is the similar solution for your problem in which user has passed order details. [Click Here](https://www.drupal.org/node/2169027#comment-8353627)

Comment: Question: how is this function 'aware' of $form_state['values'] if it's not passed as a parameter? is it a persistent variable? it doesn't seem like it would be.

Comment: @Sage : Every form has their own submit handler and you can save your form data in **form_state['storage']** or your custom table table or you can get your data in an array and save it to variable table using `drupal_get/drupal_put` function for after use.